# Upper limit on facebook user logins for mobile

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile

I am struggling with a request from a customer to build an application that lets users at an event log into their facebook account and post photos to their walls.

The concern that has come up is that Facebook may not allow too many different users on one device. Is there any guidance out there on how an app should behave given that use case?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226950/facebook-ios-sdk-logout-question)

i dont think what you are doing is possible unless you build your own login mechanism rather than using the facebookSDK