# Facebook logout after posting iOS- Kiosk App

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, kiosk

I have a kiosk app. I need users to login to post on facebook and immediately after posting force the facebook account to expire or logout.

In my understanding, I though couldn´t use the Social Framework of ios 6 because doesn´t work for the login/logout of many different users  because it´s attached to an account in the settings of the device. So, I used an old code  Facebook  of Andy Yanok prior to ios5. Everything works perfect, except that so far I am not able to logout the session, after posting. At the moment I am looking for alternatives, maybe with the ios facebook SDk or inside the facebook app. I have cero experience with facebook apps so I have no idea if that is possible.

So, I would like to know if someone has experience with implementing facebook on an ipad kiosk. And how can I perform log-in window, posting and logout in the easiest way. If this can be done with the fb sdk or which is the fastest alternative.

If the facebook app is the option, please explain with detail , like I said I have very little experience making facebook apps.

Thanks!!

Comment: You can absolutely use the Facebook SDK for this use case. There's an option when you open a Session to not use the Facebook app, and to use the browser (or webview) instead. It also gives you an option to logout (by closing the Session and clearing any cached data).

Comment: Yeah , I also found out that looking at the fb sdk  tutorials. Stupid that I didn´t do that from the beginning instead of assuming would be better to use old facebook codes. I will post my code soon for other kiosk developers. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok the solution I used for this was to use the same Facebook code I already had and add some additional code to the log-out in the Facebook.m to delete the cookies. I found the code to implement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226950/facebook-ios-sdk-logout-question)