# Phonegap fabebook SDK - FB.logout not working

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, logout

I am using `fabebook SDK` for my ios application. All actions are working fine. But logout is not working.

```
function fb_logout() 
{
    FB.logout(function(response) {
       alert('logged out');
    });
}
```

I tried adding alert before `FB.logout` call- this alert is triggering, but FB.logout is not working.

Comment: Any error you getting in the console?

Comment: @Shadowfax, No. I am not getting any error on console. no action happens after FB.logout event line is called.

Comment: @RakeshOstwal I am having the same problem. Have you fixed it? Please share.

Comment: @ErmaIsabel: No, i have no luck for this issue. I am also looking for it.

Comment: @RakeshOstwal Any luck? Am pulling my hair out.

Comment: @Erma Isabel FB.logout() function is seems to not working. After trying several option i got: 
`FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(null, 'unknown');

 fb_loginStatus();` Make Token of Logged in user to null and then check status of user. But When you start App again this user becomes a valied User, as he was not logged out from application previously.  It didn't helped me though. May it help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Cordova Facebook Plugin is SingleSignOn.The issue with singleSignOn is specified in the below link.
[facebook-ios-sdk logout question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226950/facebook-ios-sdk-logout-question)
so itz better try facebook using childbrowser.

Comment: Yeah i also got that.